# merging 2 wicket web projects into 1 multi-module maven project

Tags: jakarta-ee, maven, wicket, web-inf

I have created 2 separate wicket web projects. Now i want put them together in  multi-module maven project and put the dependency as required. 
Will it give problem when i have have web-inf folders.
Example
Project A has web-inf
Project B also has web-inf.

Now i put both Project "A" and "B" into a multi-module maven Project named "C", and have the pom.xml of project "B" changed so it includes the dependency of "A"

Finally i want to deploy war of project "B".

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend to create another Maven module "D" (with *jar* packaging) which would contain all the shared code between modules "A" and "B".

The module "A" will need to have a dependency on "D" and the module "B" will need to have a dependency on "D" as well.

The benefit of this approach is to have both web projects ("A", "B") still able to deploy to a web server while maintaining the code shared between them on one place ("D").

Comment: Note to WAR-WAR dependency: WAR requires a different directory structure as JAR (e.g. the _WEB-INF_ directory with _classes_ and _lib_ subdirectories as you have already mentioned) so I think a dependency on a WAR module will not work for you as you would expect.